# Extracting from list with variable indices

Tags: functions, list-manipulation

I am trying to extract from a list `L` the elements

```
Extract[L, {i, j}]
```

where {i, j} are defined beforehand in a list, i.e., {{i1, j1},{i2, j2}, ...}.

Is there a way to let mathematica save this expression and not output the error below?

```
Extract::psl1: Position specification {i, j} in Extract[L,{i, j}] is not applicable.
```

Comment: Use [`Indexed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Indexed) instead of [`Extract`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Extract)

Answer (score 3):

First, never use upper-case letters to name a variable as it may conflict with an internal function or constant name.

```
Indexed[L, #] & /@ {{4, 5}, {2, 1}}
```

Comment: Sorry. I should have clarified that `{i, j}` are iterated variables say from $1$ to $n$.

Comment: Isn't this then just retrieving `L` in its entirety??  WHAT are you *really* trying to do?  Please give a concrete example... not the vague and misleading explanation that has potential helpers confused.

Comment: The indices are taken from a list `coords = {{i1, j1}, ..., {in, jn}}`, and I'm trying to get the list `{L[[i1, j1]], ..., L[[in, jn]]}`.

Comment: @user54314 `list[[#[[1]], #[[2]]]] & /@ coords `

Comment: Or `list[[Sequence @@ #]] & /@ coords`. Note: edit your question instead of clarifying it in a comment.

Answer (score 1):

```
mL = RandomInteger[100, {50, 50}];
mCoords = RandomInteger[50, {25, 2}];
Extract[mL, mCoords]
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment above:

```
coords={{4, 5}, {2, 1}}
Table[{ip,jp}=pair; L[[ip,jp]],{pair,coords}]
```

Comment: Or `Table[L[[Sequence@@pair]],{pair,coords}]`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a matrix

```
SeedRandom[1]
l = RandomInteger[10, {20, 20}];
```

and a list of positions of the elements you want to extract

```
pos = RandomInteger[{1, 20}, {10, 2}];
```

Then

```
l[[##]] & @@@ pos
```

is probably the easist way to go.